# How do I make a pygame.draw.rect detect collision with a pygame.surface?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

The title basically explain it all. Here's the code for the pygame.draw.rect:

```py
stand = pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (spike_x + 900, 400 - player_y + 476, 500, 500), border_radius=15)
```

I want the `stand` to be able to collide with the player. The player is using a rect collision box:

```py
player_collision = player.get_rect(topleft=(player_x, player_y))
```

I've tried to use `if player_collsion.collidepoint(stand):`, but it doesn't work. When I try that, it says `TypeError: argument must contain two numbers`

Comment: When you looked into the documentation for `collidepoint` what did they they tell you the arguments were?  Can you somehow get the two numbers out of the `stand` object?

Comment: ... try `if player_collsion.colliderect(stand):`, compare [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) and [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) rather than [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint). `collidepoint` is used to compare a rectangle and a point, `colliderect` is used to compare 2 rectangles:

<s>`if player_collsion.collidepoint(stand):`</s>

```c
if player_collsion.colliderect(stand):
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I guess I didn't understand the `collidepoint` function well enough....